# Using bassistance's jQuery Validation plug-in, how can I validate the form programatically without triggering the error messages?

Tags: jquery, validation

The question is a bit complicated. Let me preface this question with the end goal.

**Goal**
I would like to run some kind of code that will check the validity of the form using the validate plug-in but not trigger the errors messages. I would like the Submit action of the form to follow the same rules, but then throw the errors.

Basically, I want to disable the Submit button until the form is completely valid. Therefore, anytime a field is changed, I need to check to see all the rules are satisfied. This process triggers the errors to be shown. This (in my case) is problematic.

**Question**
Does anyone know of a way to check the validity of the form using the Validation plug-in to just return a boolean true or false without triggering the errors messages any time anything on the form is changed?

**What I've Tried**
I have tried using the `success` method, however this only works after the form has been submitted and it only directly affects the field that was changed, not the form as a whole.

I've also tried to use `$('#start_date').valid()`, however as I have said above, this triggers the errors to display on the form.

Any ideas?

The plug-in (so there's no confusion): [bassistance's jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dove into the actual source code of the plug-in last night and actually found an undocumented method that does exactly what I want!

`$('#formname').validate().checkForm()` - Returns true or false based on whether or not the form is valid, without triggering the error messages.

I don't know why this method isn't documented, but it really should be.

My implementation of it to disable or enable the Submit button is working like this:

```
$('#formname').bind('change keyup', function() {
        if($(this).validate().checkForm()) {
            $('#submitbutton').removeClass('button_disabled').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#submitbutton').addClass('button_disabled').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way I could think of would be to use a custom validation error message placement function that did nothing if you were trying to avoid triggering the errors. So something like:

```
var hideerrors = false;
form.validate({ errorClass: "err",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        if(hideerrors) return;
            error.appendTo(element.parent("div").next("div.errlabel"));
            }
        });
```

Then when you want to validate you can just set `hideerrors` to true, call `validate`, then set `hideerrors` to false again.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I actually got this to work before I discovered a way to do it with an actual undocumented method. +1

Comment: Do share what that undocumented method was :)